# Output of Two Functions as a Single Function

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

I have two functions: One of which outputs a number and the other outputs a picture.  What I would like to do is create a single function that would output both the number and the picture.

As a MWE take the following:

```
Tri = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]
PictureTest[x_, y_, z_] := 
RegionPlot[x >= z*y && {x, y} ∈ Tri, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
MinTest[x_, y_, z_] := Minimize[{x, x >= y + z && {x, y} ∈ Tri}, {x, y}]
```

I would like to create a new function NewFunc[x_,y_] that gives as an output both PictureTest[x,y,z] and MinTest[x,y,z]. (Or even better if it added some words and gave PictureTest[x,y,z] and "the minimum is MinTest[x,y,z].")

(This might seem silly given the specific functions above.  But I'm working with more complicated functions and z is in fact many variables.  So, in practice, I'd like to input "z" once and get the answer to both PictureTest and MinText. I imagine the answer is in the Mathematica documentation, but I don't quite know what I am looking for. I'm not even sure if I'm using the correct tags.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
ClearAll[pictureTest, minTest, newFunc]
pictureTest[z_] := RegionPlot[x >= z*y && {x, y} ∈ Tri, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

minTest[z_] := Minimize[{x, x >= y + z && {x, y} ∈ Tri}, {x, y}]
```

You can use [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) to get a list of results from applying a list of functions to a given input:

```
newFunc[z_] := Through[{pictureTest, minTest}@z]

newFunc[.5]
```

[image]

Comment: better? `Through[Labeled[pictureTest, minTest]@z]`